# Как из строки добавить числа в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как из строки достать все числа и поместить их в список.
Именно числа, а не отдельные цифры. Например:

```
pre = input('Введите a, b, c через пробел: ').strip() #67ds55 44dg4 54g
pre2 = ''.join(i + ' ' for i in pre if i.isdigit())
print(pre2) #6 7 5 5 4 4 4 5 4
```

Необходимо, чтоб `pre2` был списком (в моем примере строка), который принимает цифры не по одному, а по числам, если цифры стоят рядом, например `['67', '55', '44', '4', '54']`. Ну и если возможно сделать это с дробными числами, то только лучше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
pre = input('Введите a, b, c через пробел: ').strip() #67ds55 44dg4 54g v22.5ger
pre2 = re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', pre)
print(pre2)
# ['67', '55', '44', '4', '54', '22.5']
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то вынести отрицательные числа, если они имеются в строке

Comment: @АлександрБоканов да, я немного исправил выражение, взгляните.

Comment: Великолепно, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby

pre2 = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(pre, key=str.isdigit) if k]
```